# Resize/ Binning of encrypted video stream

Tags: c++, c, encryption, stream, mpeg

Is it possible to do binning/resizing on encrypted video streams such as MPEG Frames?

(Without decryption -> resize -> encryption)

Also is there any C/C++ Code for this?

Comment: I don't think so it will be possible without decryption. how such action can be performed on compressed frame.

Comment: This will entirely depend on the form of encryption being used. There are algorithms that can operate on specific forms of encryption without needing to decrypt. Specifying more specifically what encryption is being used and any other relevant information will allow someone to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption methods might vary, however with majority, if not all of them, including popular such as MPEG-CENC, decryption will have to be first processing step. With popular video encodings such as H.264, H.265 you will have to decode after decryption too, before the video feed can be resized.

That is, to, for example, resize, you would typically have to decrypt, decode, resize, encode and then encrypt again.